# How to detect onclick on Kinetic JS layer.children?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

So I have to make a webpage, where there is a piece of furniture and you can color its parts.
First you have to choose a colour, then click on a shelf or box.

I have made this so far:

http://tone-me.com/gridalea/tone.html

The only problem I got is when I add color to a box,shelf. For the first box,shelf it works fine, but when I try to do it again, it won't fire the onclick event. Nothing happens.My concept is that I delete the whole model, then re-draw it, with the selected olour. But when I try to modify the re-drawn model nothing will happen. Tested it so many times, with other solutions too (e.g. where I redrew only the part which is clicked).

This is my script:
http://tone-me.com/gridalea/js/tone.js

This part re-draws the whole model:

```
function model1(){
        layer.destroyChildren();
        layer.clearCache();
        racs1();           //adds outlines to layer
        dobozok1();        //adds boxes, shelves, etc. to layer
        stage.add(layer);
    };
```

Here is the click detection:

```
layer.children.on('click', function() {
    var name=this.attrs.name;
    switch (name){
        case 'topl':
            bc[2]=[res[0],res[1],res[2],1];
        break;
        case 'topb':
            bc[3]=[res[0],res[1],res[2],1];
        break;
        case 'midr':
            bc[4]=[res[0],res[1],res[2],1];
        break;
        case 'mids':
            bc[5]=[res[0],res[1],res[2],1];
        break;
        case 'bottoms':
            bc[6]=[res[0],res[1],res[2],1];
        break;
        case 'bottomb':
            bc[7]=[res[0],res[1],res[2],1];
        break;
        default:
    };
    model1();
});
```

When it fires, I change the `bc` array which contains the colours of the boxes and the array `res` has the new values.

Then I run the `model1` function shown above, which destroys everithing, then redraws them with the modified colors.

I tested it with Firebug, every variable and object has their correct values set, (array `res` is the exception, you have to first click on a color, to make it get its value, I'll fix that later)
I don't know what the problem is. Why it won't detect more than one clicks. The `layer` has the children polygons after being redrawn, the polygons have their name attributes correctly, but it wont detect them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with [this project](https://github.com/flibbertigibbet/tessellate-kinetic), and eventually got around it by re-creating the entire `Stage` and all its contents.

Comment: how did you recreate the Stage?

Comment: I simply re-declare it: `stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container:"myCanvas",
      width:window.innerWidth,
      height:window.innerHeight
    });`  Also, when tearing down a layer, I do so with `layer.destroyChildren();
      layer.destroy();`

Comment: before redrawing th thing?

Comment: Yes, then I create and add a new layer and contents.

Comment: But it does not work for me. Dont know why. I updated the page

Comment: Perhaps it's hanging on to a reference to something.

Comment: Would you be so kind and take a look at my code, and suggest anything specific? Please

Comment: Okay, perhaps instead of `layer.destroyChildren(); layer.clearCache(); model1();` you could try `layer.destroyChildren(); layer.destroy(); model1();`

Comment: I see there are two things named 'poly', a Polygon and an Ellipse.  Perhaps kineticjs is having a namespace clash with those.  I had an issue where it would see something outside of its scope.

Comment: fixed that, but did not help. :S but thanks! any other suggestions?

Comment: The layer.children.on events I think need to be added within init(), or else they might disappear when the layer is re-created.  Also, I don't think it will work properly to tell the layer to destroy itself in its own .on('click'), but it should be destroyed before being re-created.  Maybe put its content into a group, and destroy/recreate that instead.

Comment: When I add it to init() it won't detect the events!